# Apache2.4 AddType for PHP 5.6 Fails/Ignored

Tags: apache-2.4, php5

Thank you for your time reading this post. Server config given to configure (I can't change) [snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQn73.png)

Please note I can't use `add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`, I tried but installing php5.6 packages fails silently as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne5XU.png).

I have followed the below steps to configure the above LAMP stack:

```
wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-5.6.40.tar.gz

tar -zxvf php-5.6.40.tar.gz

sudo -i

apt install software-properties-common

apt-get update

apt-get install apache2 apache2-dev libxml2-dev  libcurl4-openssl-dev libjpeg-dev  libpng-dev    libxpm-dev  libmysqlclient-dev  libpq-dev libicu-dev libfreetype6-dev  libldap2-dev libxslt-dev  libssl-dev libldb-dev

ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap.so /usr/lib/libldap.so

ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber.so /usr/lib/liblber.so

apt-get install build-essential

cd /home/ubuntu/php-5.6.40

./configure \
 --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs \
  --prefix=/usr/local/php \
  --enable-mbstring \
  --with-curl \
  --with-openssl \
  --with-xmlrpc \
  --enable-soap \
  --enable-zip \
  --with-gd \
  --with-jpeg-dir \
  --with-png-dir \
  --with-mysqli \
  --with-mysql \
  --with-pgsql \
  --enable-embedded-mysqli \
  --with-freetype-dir \
  --with-ldap \
  --enable-intl \
  --with-xsl \
  --with-sqlite3 \
  --with-zlib

make clean
make
make install
cp php.ini-production /usr/local/lib/php.ini
ln -s /usr/local/lib/php.ini /etc
ln -s /usr/local/php/bin/php /usr/bin/php

vim  /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
-------
LoadModule php5_module  modules/libphp5.so
AddType application/x-http-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php 
AddType text/x-php .php
DirectoryIndex  index.php  index.html
-------

a2enmod php5
a2dismod mpm_event
a2enmod mpm_prefork

service apache2 restart
```

Post all above given steps, I made a test file, but php [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWf7l.png) gets downloaded instead of executing and sending php info on the browser. This is my [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ5Ga.png), any pointers to fix the issue are welcome.

Comment: Did you install the `libapache2-mod-php` package before trying to compile your own PHP? Without it, Apache will not use the installed PHP environment. If you hadn't, then you should install that package, so you won't need to compile anything.

Comment: @Lacek `modules/libphp5.so` was already compiled at first stage

Comment: Plus, PHP 5.6 is not available  even after adding `ppa:ondrej/php`. Hence I had to compile PHP